# Should I remap string keys into integers for stoing attributes in a collecion? Java

Tags: java, optimization, data-representation

I have a very moddable system where I store properties in a HashMap. The key is a String and the values are a hierachy of Value classes.

The code accesses the Map extremely often in my project, to the point of having the hashmap access & string proccessing be the dominant cost in the profiler.

I'm wondering if performance can be improved if I map Strings into Integers and have the container switched from a hashmap to an array. The String keys are not adhoc, they are finite and I will know all strings to be used at init, passed by to me by the class user.

I will have the following coding/usage overheads:

1. Registering keys at the start.
2. Converting strings to indexes at runtime on each request, if I wish to keep the same class interface.
3. Manage serialization of these intemediate mappings as well.

If I also switch the class interface (quite painfull but,can do), I can get rid of Strings altogether, in my processing phase, by only using them on data setup configuration.

But will there be a substantial benefit or am I just wasting time?

Comment: As a first step you might call `intern` on the Strings before using them as key to the map. String's `equals` implementation checks first if `this == object`, so there is no iteration over the actual text if that's the case.

Comment: @Lothar wow string intering - I completely missed that!! Many thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've already did profiling.It's  mentioned in my secong paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you described of mapping Strings to Integers and then using the Integers as indices into an array is actually the basis of a primitive HashMap implementation! Internally Java's HashMap class is doing something similar, but a bit more advanced.

I wouldn't recommend going down this route. Many libraries have tried to beat the performance of Java's HashMap class, but none have been able to do much better. See the benchmark [here](http://www.klewitz.info/2013/10/18/java-hashmap-performance/).

If you need to improve performance and most of your time is spent in the HashMap, consider dividing your data into multiple HashMaps and processing your data across multiple threads. This should give you a substantial performance improvement, but you will need to give more details about your use case in order to see if this is really possible for your situation.

Comment: I know about the implementation. My concern is that the heavyweight here is the sting itself. Granted, most keys I use are not very long, but I can live with a 32bit integer key. My thought was on completely abstracting the string, even from the API itself to make it lighter and dare I say more cache friendly?

Comment: If you have a straight forward way to map a string to a unique integer or a long (without conflicts) then you cold explore using fast util which has efficient maps for handling primitive values as keys. http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/Int2ObjectMap.html . Using an array instead of a map is tough because you would have to handle the event of a conflict.

Comment: the idea is to hand out integers incrementally on a first come first reserved basis since no new key entries are allowed after init and have client code hold final/constant values. So strings are irrelevant once the structure is set up. This could also be reversed when serializing to write the actual strings. But I can see this rewrite taking considerable time.

Comment: I'm accepting this, your hash performance link was quite informative.